# How to write "Author equally contributed" in a Latex file?

Tags: author, contribute

I'm writing a paper using `IEEEtrans` in conference mode (http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html)

I notice that in some paper people can note that "Author equally contributed" like this one:
[image]

So how to write this for several specific authors? Can you give me a sample of code? I've searched on google but haven't found appropriate answer.

Many thanks,

Comment: Sounds like `\thanks` might be a good option. But really, no way to say without an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do not have a MWE, I am assuming you are using the `IEEEtran` conference mode.
In this case, you cannot use `\thanks` as it is intentionally disabled.

You can, however simply add another `IEEEauthorblockA` with your comment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Michael Shell\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}\IEEEauthorrefmark{5}, Homer Simpson\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}\IEEEauthorrefmark{5}, James Kirk\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}, Montgomery Scott\IEEEauthorrefmark{3} and Eldon Tyrell\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}School of Electrical and Computer Engineering\\
Georgia Institute of Technology, Atlanta, Georgia 30
332--0250\\
Email: mshell@ece.gatech.edu}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Twentieth Century Fox, Springfield, USA\\
Email: homer@thesimpsons.com}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}Starfleet Academy, San Francisco, California 96678-2391\\
Telephone: (800) 555--1212, Fax: (888) 555--1212}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}Tyrell Inc.,123 Replicant Street, Los Angeles, California 90210--4321}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{5} All THESE authors contributed something}}


\title{Test Title\footnote{All authors are test}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry but I think this isn't the solution. For example, in your MWE, I want to say that Michael Shell and Homer Simpson has equally contributed, your solution won't work.

Comment: This is a different question than what you asked originally. I've edited both your question and my answer.

Comment: yes, this's exactly what I want. Thanks for your help!